# Asp.Net MVC How to send Updated model to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am making an app that will trigger timers on my webpage whenever certain voice commands are spoken with the help of

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;
```

My voice recognition works. Goal: Every time a phrase is recognized, to send that phrase to the view, where I can start and stop timers based on the recognized phrase.

I know how to simply send a model to my view:

```
return View(SpeechRecognition.RecognizedPhrase);
```

But how can I accomplish sending a new phrase to my view everytime one is recognized? I dont want to return a new View every time, I just want to update the current model already inside my view every time a new phrase is recognized. How can I accomplish this?

My Controller

```
public class MapsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Maps
    public async Task<ActionResult> CursedHollow()
    {
        try
        {
           SpeechRecognition.GrammarRecognized += OnGrammarRecognized;
           var t = Task.Run(() => SpeechRecognition.Init());
           t.Wait();

           if(!SpeechRecognition.isCurrentlyListening)
           {
               SpeechRecognition.StartListening();
           }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        //****I WANT TO SEND THE UPDATED RECOGNIZED PHRASE HERE, BUT NOT RETURN A WHOLE VIEW
        return View(SpeechRecognition.RecognizedPhrase);
    }

    public static void OnGrammarRecognized(SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Recognized grammar from controller: " + SpeechRecognition.RecognizedPhrase);

    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `WebAPI` so there is no need to reload the page and it works in the back end  or a `PartialView`, and reload only the partial view instead of whole page

Answer (score 0):

Use PartialView and Update the Partial View using Ajax.